# Is there any way to add texts in leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

I used leaflet's L.imageOverlay to show svg file. Now I want to create texts in some points in that overlay. I saw that its possible to create permanent labels for marker. But I want to show that text in the map itself, not in the popup. Is there any way to do this?

```
var imageUrl = "/myfile.svg",
 imageBounds = [
            [height, width],
            [0, 0]
        ];
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);

var marker = new L.marker([pointY, pointX], { opacity: 0.01 });
marker.bindTooltip("text here", { permanent: true, offset: [0, 12] }).addTo(map); //this text appears as a popup
```

Also is there any possibility to create new svg texts in this leaflet map?

Comment: One approach is to edit the SVG and add some `<text>`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have already added that svg as an overlay. So if I want to edit svg I have to save all newly added texts in that svg and have to call the L.imageOverlay again. Right? I don't think it is the proper way to do that.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Added the sample code